# Distance between two objects using method Comparison

Tags: java

After researching a little bit, I couldn't figure out how to create a obj1 distance to be able to compare with obj2. All these methods were given in assessment I had so, no chance to change logic of it. I suppose to return 3 Strings answer depending of the data. Thanks a lot in advance guys. I've attached a pease of pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZs6S.png)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Distance dist1 = new DistanceImplementation();
        Distance obj2 = new DistanceImplementation();

        dist1.setFeetAndInches(1, 8);
        obj2.setFeetAndInches(3, 5);

        System.out.println(dist1.getDistanceComparison(obj2));

    }
}

public abstract class Distance {

    protected int feet;
    protected float inches;

    abstract public void setFeetAndInches(int feet, float inches);

    abstract public int getFeet();

    abstract public float getInches();

    abstract String getDistanceComparison(Distance dist2);

}

class DistanceImplementation extends Distance {


    @Override
    public void setFeetAndInches(int feet, float inches) {
        this.feet = feet;
        this.inches = inches;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFeet() {
        return this.feet;
    }

    @Override
    public float getInches() {
        return this.inches;
    }

    @Override
    String getDistanceComparison(Distance dist2) {

        // if (dist2) { ????????????

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried comparing the feet and inches of `this` with those of the other `dist2` object?

Comment: Also, while I understand that the code is given and the general structure can not be changed, it would really be better to implement `Comparator<Distance>` and implement the method according to the interface.

Comment: (Can't edit my old comment; of course I meant "implement `Comparable<Distance>`")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after reading the assessment, I think that you can safely assume that `1 foot = 12 inches`. So, in order to correctly implement the `getDistanceComparison` method, you could calculate the *total distance **in inches*** for both the current object and the parameter, compare them and then return the corresponding string value.

Suppose you have the following method:

```
private float getTotalInches() {
    return (float) feet * 12.0 + inches;
}
```

This method returns the total inches of this `DistanceImplementation` instance, taking into account the `feet` and the `inches` attributes.

Please note that for the total result to be of type `float`, we need to first *cast* the `feet` attribute to `float`, so that it actually becomes of type `float`. Then, we multiply by `12.0` (note the `.0`, it's important because it indicates that the `12.0` literal value is also a `float`). Then, we are summing two `float` values, which yields a result of type `float`. While all this casting and convertions are not always necessary (sometimes the compiler is smart enough as to guess the correct types and preserve decimal precision), it's considred good practice to make your intentions crystal-clear, so that future developers that will maintain your code know what you have tried to accomplish.

Then, once you have this method, it would be easy to compare the total inches of both `DistanceImplementation` instances and return the corresponding string:

```
@Override
String getDistanceComparison(Distance dist2) {

    float myTotalInches = getTotalInches();
    float otherTotalInches = dist2.getTotalInches();

    if (myTotalInches > otherTotalInches) {
        // return ...
    } else if (myTotalInches < otherTotalInches) {
        // return ...
    } else {
        // return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In the assessment, it says 1 foot, 6 inches is a total of 18 inches

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on which I was working and it might be useful as well

```
package com.prog;

import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Distance {
    protected int feet;
    protected float inches;

    abstract public void setFeetAndInches(int feet, float inches);
    abstract public int getFeet();
    abstract public float getInches();
    abstract String getDistanceComparison(Distance dist2);

}

public class DistanceCalculator {
private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Distance dist1 = new DistanceImplementation();
        Distance dist2 = new DistanceImplementation();

        int feet1 = 1;
        float inches1 = (float) 2.0;

        int feet2 = 3;
        float inches2 = (float) 4.1;

        dist1.setFeetAndInches(feet1, inches1);
        dist2.setFeetAndInches(feet2, inches2);

        System.out.println(dist1.getDistanceComparison(dist2));
    }
}

package com.prog;

public class DistanceImplementation extends Distance {

    @Override
    public void setFeetAndInches(int feet, float inches) {
        this.feet=(int) (feet+ (inches/12));
        this.inches=inches+ (feet*12);

    }

    @Override
    public int getFeet() {

        return feet;
    }

    @Override
    public float getInches() {

        return inches;
    }

    @Override
    String getDistanceComparison(Distance dist2) {
        String ret;
        int dist1a=this.getFeet();
        System.out.println(dist1a);
        int dist2a=dist2.getFeet();
        if(dist1a > dist2a)
            return "First is greater";
        else if(dist1a < dist2a)
            return "Second is greater";
        else


    return "Both are equal";
    }

}
```